# Django model editable but hide in main page

Tags: python-3.x, django, foreign-keys, django-admin

I want to hide my model from Django main page administration but it can be editable as a foreign key in other models. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`has_module_permission()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_module_permission).

In your case:

```
class ModelAdminToHide(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return False
```